# xcode crash each time I try to modify my source code

Tags: xcode, crash

I'm using Xcode 4.6.1 on OSX Mountain Lion 10.8.3

I have moved my source code from my macbook air to my iMac this morning.

And now, each time I try to modify my source code, XCode crashes!

For example, if I start to write something like this :
  [ [ anyclass

XCode will crash with this message : **Cannot add another user snippet with the same identifier, you can only override system snippets.**

But if I writes the code in a text editor before, and then if I pastes it to XCode, it works!

I don't understand ... I have emptied my derived data, cleaned my project, emptied the /var/folders directory, rebooted my iMac ...

Many thanks for your help!

```
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4H512
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDECodeSnippetLibrary/IDECodeSnippetLibrary-2055/Source/IDECodeSnippetRepository.m:320
Details:  Cannot add another user snippet with the same identifier, you can only override system snippets.
Object:   <IDECodeSnippetRepository: 0x4050a98c0>
Method:   -addCodeSnippet:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40030a220>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010b681a2a -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010a9255f4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010f40f975 -[IDECodeSnippetRepository addCodeSnippet:] (in IDECodeSnippetLibrary)
  3  0x000000010f40fcfb -[IDECodeSnippetRepository _loadUserCodeSnippets] (in IDECodeSnippetLibrary)
  4  0x000000010f40ee63 -[IDECodeSnippetRepository init] (in IDECodeSnippetLibrary)
  5  0x000000010f4150c4 __44+[IDECodeSnippetRepository sharedRepository]_block_invoke (in IDECodeSnippetLibrary)
  6  0x00007fff94b950b6 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  7  0x00007fff94b95041 dispatch_once_f (in libdispatch.dylib)
  8  0x000000010f40ecaa +[IDECodeSnippetRepository sharedRepository] (in IDECodeSnippetLibrary)
  9  0x000000010f416cbe __102+[IDECodeSnippetLibraryCompletionStrategy _generateCompletionsForScopes:language:platformNames:atBOL:]_block_invoke (in IDECodeSnippetLibrary)
```

Comment: sounds like it might be related to Xcode code snippets. Try to remove the files at `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets`

Comment: @Matthias, You were right! This is because DropBox has detected some conflicts in my snippets folder. In that situation, Dropbox make a copy of the file with the .conflict extension but with the same name. And, for XCode, it appeared that 2 snippets had the same name. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving full credit to [Matthias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/457406/matthias-bauch), the problem appears to be tightly related to using a cloud source for your code snippets.  I did this a long time ago and love the seamless availability of my custom code snippets on all my Macs (iMac 27" at work, rMBPro and MBAir). This kind of cloud storage of code snippets also makes for quick setting up of a new Mac.  Yesterday, I dug out an old MBAir that I was using for development a year or so ago, when I synced Dropbox, there must have been some conflicts with my snippets that I changed since I last used said MBAir.  Dropbox appends to the name a short piece of text indicating it is a conflicting copy.  Unfortunately, Xcode doesn't see this as a different file and thinks it is a duplicate (which ain't allowed).

To solve, I just deleted the conflicting copies (all of them were the old versions), fired up Xcode and no problems.

If anyone is interested about doing this kind of Dropbox syncing of snippets:

http://irockios.com/xcode-code-snippets-everywhere/

Answer (score 0):

It related to xcode code snippets. With xcode 5.1, I add my snippet code in to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SystemCodeSnippets.codesnippets, when I try to modify my source code, XCode crashes!

so i remove all my snippet code in SystemCodeSnippets.codesnippets, xcode work well now!

Comment: this is not a answer of OP's Question.